# Grid Or List View With Customized X And Y Axises in Yii

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I'm looking for a solution to create a grid view or list view in Yii, which shows days of the actual week on the X axis on the top and menu items of a menu card on the Y axis (left side).

I store menus for particular days in a table and I would like to represent data in a grid view. Something like this:

[image]

Currently I'm using bootstrap's TbGridView but I'm looking for a theoretical solution, so if you know how to achieve this in a normal gridview then it's also fine with me.

Thanks in advace,
g0m3z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least what I've found is it's a pain. Because your date columns are the ones you really have in rows, you'll need to switch your dataprovider to a CArrayDataProvider and switch your data around by hand. If you find something easier, I'd love to know :-)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to figure out something.

Comment: You were right! To accomplish a custom grid view you need to get your hands dirty. But it's really not a big deal with Yii. I used CSqlDataprovider to achieve my goal. Just had time to create a post about how I did it. I hope it's helpful for others : [How to create custom CGridView in Yii](http://redevtion.blogspot.hu/2014/04/how-to-create-custom-cgridview-in-yii.html). Thanks for your support!